# How to use imagesInEinsteinBot in Messaging?

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I am following this guide: https://heysalesforce.org/posts/use-images-and-videos-in-einstein-bot

he learns how to customize the text in Einstein Bot and this works in chat but I need to use this package in Messaging, the bot will stay in WhatsApp and don't have Messaging in Embedded Service, in this part of documentation I stopped.

How to use imagesInEinsteinBot in Messaging?

Comment: Did you find anything, Arthur?

Comment: yes, this guide only works in chat, for WhatsApp I used this guide: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-format-your-messages

Comment: Perfect, but it still does not tell how to show images?

Comment: we cannot send images via Whatsapp using eisntein bot...

Comment: Thanks, It's going to be blocker in our project as we were confident enough that it will be supported.

Comment: send a link to the user...

Comment: Yes, that can work. Thanks for tip.